# How to fix the 'Unexpected token' error in svelte js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svelte, sveltekit

I created the following code called "Markdown.svelte" using SvelteMarkdown to mimic ReactMarkdown.

```
<script lang="ts">
  import { SvelteMarkdown, RemarkPlugins } from "svelte-markdown";
  import remarkGfm from "remark-gfm";
  import remarkMath from "remark-math";
  import { CodeBlock } from "./Codeblock.svelte";
  import P from './P.svelte';
  
  export let content: string;
</script>

<SvelteMarkdown
  class="prose dark:prose-invert prose-p:leading-relaxed prose-pre:p-0 break-words"
  remarkPlugins={[remarkGfm, remarkMath]}
  let:components={{
    p: ({childre}) => {
      return <p class="mb-2 last:mb-0">{children}</p>;
    },
    code:({childre}) => {
      if (children.length) {
        if (children[0] == "▍") {
          return <span class="mt-1 animate-pulse cursor-default">▍</span>;
        }
        children[0] = (children[0]).replace("`▍`", "▍");
      }

      const match = /language-(\w+)/.exec(className || "");

      return inline
        ? <code class={className} {...props}>{children}</code>
        : <CodeBlock 
            key={Math.random()} 
            language={(match && match[1]) || ""} 
            value={String(children).replace(/\n$/, "")}
          />;
    }
  }}
  >
  {content}
</SvelteMarkdown>
```

But I got the Unexpected token error at <p when the code got invoked:
Markdown.svelte:14:13 Unexpected token,

```
frame: ' 12 |    let:components={{\n' +
  ' 13 |      p: ({childre}) => {\n' +
  ' 14 |        return <p class="mb-2 last:mb-0">{children}</p>;\n' +
  '                    ^\n' +**
  ' 15 |      },\n' +
  ' 16 |      code: ({childre}) => {',
code: 'parse-error',
stack: '',
loc: {
  line: 14,
  column: 13,
  file: '/home/user/projects/genai-app/frontend/src/lib/components/ui/chat/Markdown.svelte'
},
plugin: 'vite-plugin-svelte',
pluginCode: '<script lang="ts">\n' +
...... (the rest of the whole code)
```

How can I fix the error? I have tried replacing p: ({children}) with p({children}), and put the return line in single quote without any success.

Comment: no idea about svelte or svelteMarkdown - but after a quick google search, it seems you may want `paragraph:` not `p:`? though, I could be completely wrong of course

Answer (score 1):

If we focus on the following part of your code:

```js
    p: ({childre}) => {
      return <p class="mb-2 last:mb-0">{children}</p>;
    },
```

One problem is that your parameter is named `childre`, and not `children`. But this is not the error you currently get. The current problem is that you have written HTML code (`<p class="mb-2 last:mb-0">{children}</p>`) where you should write JS code, and that's why you get a parse error.

I don't know how the `<SvelteMarkdown>` should be used, so you need to read the documentation for it to learn how to use it, but maybe it's as easy to simply return a JS string that contains the HTML code, e.g.:

```js
    p: ({children}) => {
      return `<p class="mb-2 last:mb-0">${children}</p>`;
    },
```

This type of problem also exists at other places in your code.